# Paypal IPN custom confirmation mail

Tags: email, paypal, notifications, paypal-ipn

I am building a site with an online shop, which is hand-made by code. The payment is done via a Paypal button. I want to know if there is any way to make that the buyer recieves a custom designed confirmation mail including a receipt of the order. I've been investigating about Paypal IPN feature, but I get a bit lost when it comes to PHP, so I was wondering if there's any available script to make this that can be easily modified.

Maybe if is there any other way to do this (eg. using some online software, or any other Paypal function) I would be interested in knowing too.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, merchant could not modify or customize the email template which sent from PayPal to merchant or buyers.

The email is fixed template.

So if you want to sent key code to your buyers with email automatically, you need to add this functions on your system end, which needs
programming development.  To set up this functions you have to use our IPN service.

IPN(Instant Payment Notification)  is a PayPal feature that sends messages about payments
(and other transactional events) directly from PayPal to your website(s)' back-end systems.

Logic:
While a payment occurred on your PayPal account, PayPal will sent IPN message to your IPN script at the same time.
After receiving the IPN , your system can refer the IPN message to do the subsequent processing- update payment status or send email etc.
But the follow-up actions need to be integrated by your system(Including send email system).

This process is complex, but it is the only way to achieve your marketing goal.

Following and the IPN integration guide. Please kindly refer them.
 https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/